# Append tuples in order to a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I'm new in python. Is it possible to add my tuples to an empty list, but in an ordered way?

The `if i not in myTransfer:` part is also not ideal I know, but just to get a clearer output.
I tried doing it in the code below, but if there's an easier solution would be much appreciated

```py
tupDays = ('Monday', 'Wednesday', 'Monday')
tupAmount = (100,300,100)
myTransfer = []

for a in tupAmount:
    myTransfer.append(a)
    for i in tupDays:
        if i not in myTransfer:
            myTransfer.append(i)

print(myTransfer)
```

What I wanted to get is :

```
[100,Monday,200,Wednesday,100,Monday]
```

Maybe it will be better to put it in a dictionary, so it can become a key-value pairs, like below but I can't seem to grasp the built-in methods I need to use yet.

```
{
100: 'Monday',
300: 'Tuesday',
100: 'Monday'
}

Thank you so much for the help.
```

Comment: why do you need such sequence `[100,Monday,200,Wednesday,100,Monday]` ? assuming that dictionary is also acceptable

Comment: Dictionary cannot have duplicate keys, so `{
100: 'Monday',
300: 'Wednesday',
100: 'Monday'
}` becomes `{100: 'Monday', 300: 'Wednesday'}` Also choose one, you want a dictionary or a list

Comment: Hi Devesh, ah okay, then dictionary is not an option :-)

Comment: Hi Roman, assuming that I have program that saves my transfer withnthe days, and amount.. I wanted it in that order, so I can then extract it via index, since list saves it in oder an allows duplication :)

Comment: what if `tupAmount` has 4 items? and why `200` is there instaed of `300` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach consists in using [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#zip) and [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html).
Here I'm assuming that the 2 tuples have the same length.

```
import itertools

my_transfer = list(itertools.chain(*zip(tupAmount, tupDays)))
# [100, 'Monday', 300, 'Wednesday', 100, 'Monday']
```

How it works:

1) zip aggregates elements from the two tuples.

```
>>> list(zip(tupAmount, tupDays))
[(100, 'Monday'), (300, 'Wednesday'), (100, 'Monday')]
```

2) itertools.chain returns elements from the iterables. The star operator unpacks the list of tuples. This corresponds to:

```
>>> list(itertools.chain((100, 'Monday'), (300, 'Wednesday'), (100, 'Monday')))
[100, 'Monday', 300, 'Wednesday', 100, 'Monday']
```

3) finally, list() constructs a list

Comment: Thank you so much! this is what I was looking for, looks readable but a newbie like me cannot generate a method like this :), the tuples will be the same length all the time, so this is perfect :-) Could you explain it a little bit more though?

Comment: The association list `[(100, 'Monday'), (300, 'Wednesday'), (100, 'Monday)]` produced by `zip` will probably be more useful than the flattened sequence produced by `chain`.

Comment: Wow! thank you soooooooo much. Actually YOUR RIGHT, the 1 is also perfect for me, because then, its a tuple inside a list, and cannot be changed. So its more secure :) Cheers!